# Occasional (404) Not Found, for SpreadsheetsService.Query

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I use Spreadsheet API to update sheets.

At some quite rare, and random, times the SpreadsheetsService.Query returns a (404) Not Found.

It is not just because there is not internet, or the service is down, because when it happens it keep happening for this specific query but not others.

It is quite weird :) Let me know if anyone has any hints.

The code is posted here below.

```js
var requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory("Some Name");
requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", credential.Token.AccessToken));
SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("{my name}");
service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;  
SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query); //here comes the exception.
SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = null;
```

Comment: That is quite an behavior given it only happens to the specific query. It could possible be that your using the Google Sheets API v3. You may check & try the info provided from this previous related issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196211718#comment7. If it is not the case, you may want to report this issue further at https://issuetracker.google.com/ and provide all of the specific details.

Comment: Thanks Irvin. I think this is the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

gdata is the older version of Sheets API and it's shut down. See Google's announcement here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess i use some kind of a mixture appently, will have it moved and keep updated here if is solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Whats happened what that I had actually upgraded everything to V4, but then it is normal very rarely to get 404s, and off course you need to retry after a timeout.

In my case I was still using the old API in the retries and so the 404 never got saved.